# Go language: Change the build folder when running "go run"

Tags: go

Using Go on Windows, whenever I execute `go run myprog.go` from the console, Go builds a new executable with a random name somewhere on my C drive.

Is there a way to configure it so it will always build the file to a specific location, and preferably to also avoid the randomness of the name? (i.e., always build to D:\Temp\LastBuild.exe).

I was able to find some info that did not help when doing `go help run` and `go help build`. The latter had an output flag `-o outfile` but it is not accepted in `go run`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `go run`.  It's intended for quick testing out snippets of code the size of a single screenful of lines.

The working approach is

1. Edit the code.
2. `go build` it.
3. Run your executable which will have predictable name.
4. Go to step (1).

If you write tests in parallel with the implementation (and you should), this changes to

1. Edit the code.
2. Edit the test suite.
3. `go test` it.
4. Go to step (1).

Please see [this recent thread on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/RA19v18X5V4/discussion) for more insight on the same subject.

Comment: Ok - I erased my last comment, I take it back. I have changed my sublime build system to run `go build -o D:/Dev/Go/debug.exe && D:/Dev/Go/debug.exe` instead of `go run $file_name` - which gets me the result I needed without losing anything. Thanks.

Comment: @DannyB, If you're using Sublime, consider using [GoSublime](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime) with it: it has all the necessary stuff for integrating Sublime's own build system with the `go` tool.

Comment: thanks, I am using Sublime and the excellent GoSublime. But I am not crazy about its build system. So I built my own. The truth is that I would still love to have the ability to change where `go run` and `go test` build their binaries.